# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 & ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model

I just installed the beta for VS2010 Ultimate and I cannot locate the ADO.NET Entity Data Model template. I was under the impression that it as installed, can someone correct this or direct me where I can find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone viewing this question, I have figured out why. I have the VS2010 Ultimate Beta 2 and found that the ADO.NET Entity Data Model is not included, or never will be included.

I was told that VS2010 Premium, with less-capable features, has the ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

which sucks. >:|

**EDIT:**

I uninstalled Ultimate and halfway through the installation of the Premium edition, my colleague reassured me we wouldn't be using the EDM so I re-installed Ultimate (once again) and now it was there. To anyone else out there who has this problem, try what I did.

Comment: That's weird. I have beta 2 ultimate installed, and I can add an ADO.NET EDM item to my projects.

Comment: Interesting. Right-clicking on Models -> Add New Item then select Data, its there? I wonder why mines not showing up. I had a problem with VS2008 but when I downloaded the service pack, voila, it was there.

Answer (score 2):

I was running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and could not find the Entity Data Model wizard, so i installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium and voila, now I have Entity Data Model wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with the type of project you are adding the item to. I had some issues when I first installed so re-installed, without actually trying anything out.

When I wanted to add a model to a class library project at I first could not find it, however I then tried adding one to an existing WCF project, it suddenly appeared. I then went back to my library project and ta da! it was there also.

Not sure what caused this or if this is of any help to peeps reading this, but there it is, my experience with 2010 and EDM...

Comment: I tried it both on a Web project using the ASP.NET MVC, first time I tried it I couldn't find it, so I uninstalled VS2010 Ultimate and went to re-install VS2010 Premium then decided not to go Premium and went to Ultimate again and voila, it was there.